# Django - Splitting admin.py

Tags: python, django

I tried to split admin.py with the following steps but failed.
- Remove admin.py
- Create folder named "admin"
- Create files in folder "admin". modela.py, modelb.py
- Create "_ *init* _.py" and leave it empty
- In the "modela.py" file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import *

@admin.register(ModelA)
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
```

But the model is not showing in my admin site. What's wrong with the steps above or I missed anything?

Comment: I believe it is `admin.site.register()`

Comment: I am using @admin.register before I splitting it, and it is working. What should I use in this case?

Comment: I tried both @admin.register(ModelA) and admin.site.register(ModelA, ModelAAdmin) doesn't work

Comment: Could you try it without the `@`

Comment: Its not working. I am using @ before splitting the file in admin.py and it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the file is called `__init__.py`, with two underscores each side. Secondly, leaving it empty won't do anything at all; you would need to import your admin classes into that file.

Comment: I tried to import previously but there are some error in my ModelAdmin file. Importing them help in my case. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In `__init__.py` you should import the *admin files* you want to use.

```
from . import adminA.py
from . import adminB.py
```